# How to Perform Transact() On Contract Functions on Remote Node

Tags: python, web3.py, infura

I would like to call a smart contract functions using Web3 Python using the Infura mainnet node instead of a local node. I understand that I need to import the private key and use it to sign the transaction but I cannot see any examples for doing this with calling smart contracts.

The code I have is as follows but it fails as there is no wallet attached:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json
from web3.providers.rpc import HTTPProvider
contractAddress = '0xabcd'
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://mainnet.infura.io'))
with open('abcd.abi', 'r') as abi_definition:
    abi = json.load(abi_definition)
print (web3.eth.blockNumber)


fContract = web3.eth.contract(abi,contractAddress)

print ("Test",fContract.transact().test("0xabcd",100000))
```

Error:

```
ValueError: {u'message': u'gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction', u'code': -32000}
```

Comment: If you are getting familiar with Blockchain you should use a testnet such as Ropsten or Rinkeby. Using mainnet (https://mainnet.infura.io) will cost you Ether if you have a wallet (such as MetaMask) setup in your browser or fail as you do not have ether to pay for gas.

Comment: If you are happy to read a JavaScript code and understand the steps involve with signing a transaction, you could refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3js-raw & https://github.com/fidenz-chim/fundsplitter_web3jsraw.git

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [example of how to invoke a contract using a local key](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-contract-transaction) in the docs.

Docs for some of the key methods are here:

- *contract_function.*[`build_transaction()`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.contract.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.build_transaction)
- [`eth.account.sign_transaction()`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction)
- [`eth.send_raw_transaction()`](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.send_raw_transaction)

Roughly, you're going to want to:

```
txn = fContract.functions.test("0xabcd", 100000).build_transaction()
signed = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(txn, privateKey)
txn_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Comment: Hi carver, thank you. Also you missed private key: signed = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(txn, privateKey)

Comment: Hi carver, would you explain a bit in detail about how to use these functions? I tried them but they are not working. Would you have a look here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49038/how-to-call-write-functions-via-python-web3-py-w3-eth-sendrawtransaction ? Thank you